# My php code is not working when merging into a nav bar

Tags: php, html

I need some guidance.

The code which I found on a tutorial worked absoloutely fine, I want to try and use/adapt it into my nav bar on a site I'm working on.

The php code which worked fine:

```
            <?php
        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
          echo '<form action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="E-mail/Username">
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="login-submit">Login</button>
          </form>
          <a href="signup.php" class="header-signup">Signup</a>';
        }
        else if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
          echo '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
            <button type="submit" name="logout-submit">Logout</button>
          </form>';
        }
        ?>
```

The code I have which is where I need it to work (within my menu nav bar), however I think because my nav bar aren't a form/button I can't link the action tag to it:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-left" href="index.php">iStudy University <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-dark navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myTogglerNav"
                    aria-controls="myTogglerNav" aria-label="Toggle Navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>  <!-- Aria controls are for assistive screen readers -->

            <section class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myTogglerNav">
            <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Home</span></i></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="about.html"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; About</span></i></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Contact Us</span></i></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link px-3" href="signup.php"><i class="fas fa-check-square"><span class="nav-text">&nbsp; Sign Up</span></i></a>
               <?php  
                    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                      echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' name='login-submit' action='includes/login.inc.php' href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'><span class='nav-text'>&nbsp; Login</span></i></a>";
                    } else if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
                      echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' name='logout-submit' href='includes/logout.inc.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'><span class='nav-text'>&nbsp; Logout</span></i></a>";
                    }
                ?>


            </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

[image: NAVBAR]

Is there any way I can use my navbar code however use the 'action' tag and name tag, as the includes/login.inc.php includes some error handling check in on login. As when Login is clicked on, the login.inc.php file is not running.  Any help at all would be great thank you.

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? what is not working ? is your navbar inside  a .php file ? I didn't really understand what you want to achieve !

Comment: You can't submit form using <a> . You need to create a form also

Comment: Hi @AfifZafri, is there anyway that I can do that with still having it inside of the 'nav' menu tag?

Comment: Hello @Soheyl , so in the first snippet of code which works (from a tutorial), I need to take that code and adapt it into my navbar code for my menu, however the action tag doesn't seem to be working, so the includes/login.inc.php file is not running when LOGIN is clicked on. So I'm struggling with finding a solution or way around this so the file does run when clicked on LOGIN.

Comment: Put this `includes/login.inc.php` in `href` and remove `action` attribute from login `<a>` tag.

Comment: `action` attribute work only with forms

Comment: Hi @DEarTh I'm not sure if I can do that as I still want it to take the user to login.php page but also perform some code which lies inside of includes/login.inc.php. I'll perhaps have to try and turn the navbar section into a form??

Comment: What's there in `login.php` and in `login.inc.php` ?

Comment: login.php is just a html where they can pop their username and password in, and the login.inc.php is where all the php code is for error handling, assigning session variables etc. Could I just paste all the code from login.inc.php into the login.php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is what I understood from your comments,

You have your form inside login.php and your php codes to test the user email and password and other stuff are in the login.inc.php,

First to explain that, you cannot use action="" outside a form or use href="" inside a form tag, so you can :

For example, change :

```
echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' name='login-submit'
action='includes/login.inc.php' href='login.php'>
```

To :

```
echo "<a class='nav-item nav-link px-3' name='login-submit' href='login.php'>
```

Just use href="login.php" which will send the user to the login form and there you can use your form with action="login.inc.php" or add all the codes inside login.inc.php to the login.php file and run the codes once the form submitted :

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  // Run the code inside login.inc.php
} // Example to check if the form is submitted
```